# Ruby on Rails i18n change text inside Ajax

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, internationalization, highcharts

I have a Highcharts graph and there's text inside. How can I change this text according to the language selected ? Here is my code :

```
var chart;
chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
(...)
    subtitle: {
        text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
        'Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in' :
        'Drag your finger over the plot to zoom in'
        }
(...)
```

My en.yml file looks like :

```
en:
   actions:
      zoom: "Click and drag in the plot area to zoom in"
```

I have tried

```
t("actions.zoom")
```

and

```
<% t "actions.zoom" %>
```

But they are not working inside the Ajax. How should I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever your file is called, just add the `erb` extension:

`my_file.js.erb`

```
    subtitle: {
    text: document.ontouchstart === undefined ?
      <%= t "actions.zoom" %> : 'something something'
    }
```

Also note that `<%=` prints the result, `<%` does not.

EDIT:  This assumes you're using the rails asset pipeline, if you're not it will be much more complicated.

Comment: My file is called index.html.erb. I tried index.html.js.erb but then I have an error "Template is missing"

Comment: Your javascript isn't in an external js file?  Then I assume you've used `<script>` tags to put it on the html page or what?  If that's the case `<%= t "actions.zoom" %>` should work, and you didn't indicate that you had tried it with the `=`

Answer (score 0):

Try using the [i18n-js](https://github.com/fnando/i18n-js) gem to pass the Rails `I18n.locale` into your javascript files.